# How to print on a continuous stationary from ASP.NET Page

Tags: css, printing, continuous

We are trying to print variable length labels on a continuous stationary from our ASP.NET Page. We have defined the CSS print media styles including the @page directive.

The problem the Browser ignores the CSS directives and sends a 11" document to the printer as a result the printer leaves lots of blank space after it prints the label.

The printer we are using is TSC TTP-346M Barcode printer and we are printing on a 4" width media.

Can someone help us to solve our problem.

Thanks
-Surya

Answer (score 1):

Set the printer preferences in the OS to limit the height.